# Book a child/teenager discovering his power and struggling to learn to control it

Tags: story-identification, childrens-novel, powers

I am looking for a book series where each member of the family has a special ability. Each book follows a different character but they are all part of the same (larger) family.

As I remember, one of the boys can control the weather/wind (and makes it terribly bad if he doesn't control his power properly). The grandma has the power to "save" music in jar (when you open the jar, the music plays). Later in the book (series?) most or all of the jar of the (now deceased) grandma is broken and, thus, the music is permanently lost.

If I remember correctly, the main character in one of the books spent a lot of time in a car dump (working there with one or two other people).

Each book follows the story of one of the children going through their teenage years, discovering their power and learning to control it.

I believe that the last book of the series was written less than 10 years ago.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the *[Savvy](https://www.goodreads.com/series/51261-savvy)* series by Ingrid Law. Summary for [the eponymous first book of the series](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/2133795.Savvy):

> For generations, the Beaumont family has harbored a magical secret. They each possess a "savvy" -a special supernatural power that strikes when they turn thirteen. Grandpa Bomba moves mountains, her older brothers create hurricanes and spark electricity . . . and now it's the eve of Mibs's big day.
>
> As if waiting weren't hard enough, the family gets scary news two days before Mibs's birthday: Poppa has been in a terrible accident. Mibs develops the singular mission to get to the hospital and prove that her new power can save her dad. So she sneaks onto a salesman's bus . . . only to find the bus heading in the opposite direction. Suddenly Mibs finds herself on an unforgettable odyssey that will force her to make sense of growing up-and of other people, who might also have a few secrets hidden just beneath the skin.

[This review](https://www.librarything.com/work/9607168/reviews/135063496) of *Scumble*, the second book, mentions the jarred music.

> Ledger Kale is in a family that gets a "savvy" - a special talent, of sorts - on their thirteenth birthday. Unfortunately, his appears to be a really unhelpful one: he can make things fall apart. When his family is off to a cousin's wedding and he causes problems with the car, they pull over and he meets a young girl Sarah Jane, who definitely spells trouble if she finds out about his family. Plus, Ledge needs to figure out how to control, or "scumble" his savvy fast, or he'll do worse damage than making the barn fall down and crushing all the jars of music his grandma saved (true story). A summer on the farm with his uncle, sister, and a bunch of cousins may be just what he needs, if he can manage to save that jar that ending up in Sarah Jane's possession...

Found with a Google search for `science fiction novel grandmother "jars * music"`

Comment: What does the `*` mean in your search terms?

Comment: It tells Google to search for a phrase that starts with "jars" and ends with "music" with some number of words in between. That way, it matches with "jars filled with music", "jars of music", or "jars in which she stored music". :) My initial search was the same, but with "music * jars", which did not bring up anything useful.

Comment: Ooh, neat! Thanks for the tip :-) That's going to be useful.